# What is the correct way to extract multiple required patterns from a column in the data using regular expression (grepl function) in R

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, data-extraction, grepl

I have a dataframe (can also use the CSV file which I generated) that has 7 columns and close to a million rows.

I am specifically interested in fetching 5 different "ID's" from this entire string of data that is present in a single column and want to create new columns with the specific "ID" as column header name.The data looks something like this -

```
 UNIQUE-NAME    TYPES        COMMON-NAME                FORMULA                                  SOURCE                                                                                                                                                                  WEIGHT     SECONDARY-WEIGHT

 CPD-12676      Compounds    glycerophosphoglycerol     (C 19);(H 29);(N 5);(O 10);(S 2)        (SPIDER "3315400" NIL | devarsh | 3468 NIL);(PUBCHEM "54758713" NIL | ong);(SMALL "35022" | NIL | Tom);(CHEBI "28643" | NIL);(BAS "55672-34-1" | Harry | NILL)           29.83      27.65
 CPD-380        Enamines     UDP                         NA                                      NA                                                                                                                                                                      294.37     287.33
 NAD            Steroids     prephenate                 (O 4);(S 1)                             (PUBCHEM "87361293" NIL | ong);(CHEBI "87100" | NIL); (BAS "91234-28-2" | Harry | NILL)                                                                                  373.47     381.24
 ADP            Rings        pyridine                   (C 5);(H 5);(N 1)                       (SPIDER "2311345" NIL | devarsh | 6789 NIL);(SMALL "98234" | NIL | Tom)                                                                                                  39.33      40.65
 CAD-392        Molecules    pyrine                     (C 10);(H 9)                            (SPIDER "5454678" NIL | devarsh | 7688 NIL)                                                                                                                              392.543    400.656
 CAD-355        Groups       solution                   (C 12);(H 12)                            NA                                                                                                                                                                      32.53      40.66
 CPD-39234      Compounds    glycerophosphoglycerol     (C 19);(H 29);(N 5);(O 10);(S 2)        (SMALL "45465" | NIL | Harry);(CHEBI "33490" | NIL)                                                                                                                      92.43      100.65
```

Now I am interested in the "SOURCE" column and want to fetch

```
SPIDER ID, PUBCHEM ID, SMALL ID, CHEBI ID AND BAS ID
```

and create a new column in my csv file with each of these ID's as column headers and store the ID numbers as rows.

So, I want my final output table to be like this -

```
 UNIQUE-NAME    TYPES        COMMON-NAME                FORMULA                                  SMALL ID     PUBCHEM ID      SPIDER ID         CHEBI ID      BAS ID       WEIGHT     SECONDARY-WEIGHT

 CPD-12676      Compounds    glycerophosphoglycerol     (C 19);(H 29);(N 5);(O 10);(S 2)         35022        54758713        3315400           28643         55672-34-1   29.83      27.65
 CPD-380        Enamines     UDP                         NA                                      NA           NA              NA                NA            NA           294.37     287.33
 NAD            Steroids     prephenate                 (O 4);(S                                 NA           87361293        NA                87100         91234-28-2   373.47     381.24
 ADP            Rings        pyridine                   (C 5);(H 5);(N 1)                        98234        NA              2311345           NA            NA           39.33      40.65
 CAD-392        Molecules    pyrine                     (C 10);(H 9)                             NA           NA              5454678           NA            NA           392.543    400.656
 CAD-355        Groups       solution                   (C 12);(H 12)                            NA           NA              NA                NA            NA           32.53      40.66
 CPD-39234      Compounds    glycerophosphoglycerol     (C 19);(H 29);(N 5);(O 10);(S 2)         45465        NA              NA                33490         NA           92.43      100.65
```

I was using `grepl` function for achieving this result -

```
dt3 <- grepl("^[:punct:]SMALL\\s[:punct:][0-9][:punct:]|^[:punct:]SPIDER\\s[:punct:][0-9][:punct:]|[:punct:]BAS\\s[:punct:][0-9]-+[:punct:]|[:punct:]CHEBI\\s[:punct:][0-9][:punct:]|[:punct:]PUBCHEM\\s[:punct:][0-9][:punct:]", dt2$SOURCE)
```

where `dt2` is the dataframe having the data (displayed in the first table above). I am only taking the `SOURCE` column and trying to match the pattern for the columns that I want to fetch. `grepl` is not throwing any error but giving all `FALSE` values which clearly means I am doing something wrong with the regex syntax here for pattern matching and `R` is not understanding what I want to fetch.

I would really appreciate your help on this. Thanks!

Sample source data - [Sample data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YfASfHDBu9CKNWEcjmovD3EjcgEy8SBn)

Comment: Are these always in order left->right `SPIDER ID, PUBCHEM ID, SMALL ID, CHEBI ID AND BAS ID` weather there or not ?

Comment: @sln - No. They are not in the same order. The pattern is same like `parenthesis-SMALL-space-double quotes-number-double-quotes` or `parenthesis-PUBCHEM-space-double quotes-number-double-quotes`but in some rows the SPIDER occurs first in the data, it's somewhere in the middle in some rows, and in the last for some cases. The order is not the same for any of the ID's. The pattern is just slightly different for `BAS ID` as it also contains `hyphens(-)` in between numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very crude method using `dplyr` and `stringr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% # this assumes your data is in a data frame called 'df'
  mutate(small_id = str_extract(SOURCE, 'SMALL "[0-9]+"')) %>% 
  mutate(pubchem_id = str_extract(SOURCE, 'PUBCHEM "[0-9]+"')) %>% 
  mutate(spider_id = str_extract(SOURCE, 'SPIDER "[0-9]+"')) %>% 
  mutate(chebi_id = str_extract(SOURCE, 'CHEBI "[0-9]+"')) %>% 
  mutate(bas_id = str_extract(SOURCE, 'BAS "[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+"')) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with('_id')), ~gsub('[A-Z]|"|\\s+', '', .)) %>% 
  select(-SOURCE)

  `UNIQUE-NAME` TYPES     `COMMON-NAME`          FORMULA                          WEIGHT `SECONDARY-WEIGHT` small_id pubchem_id spider_id chebi_id bas_id    
  <chr>         <chr>     <chr>                  <chr>                             <dbl>              <dbl> <chr>    <chr>      <chr>     <chr>    <chr>     
1 CPD-12676     Compounds glycerophosphoglycerol (C 19);(H 29);(N 5);(O 10);(S 2)   29.8               27.6 35022    54758713   3315400   28643    55672-34-1
2 CPD-380       Enamines  UDP                    NA                                294.               287.  NA       NA         NA        NA       NA        
3 NAD           Steroids  prephenate             (O 4);(S 1)                       373.               381.  NA       87361293   NA        87100    91234-28-2
4 ADP           Rings     pyridine               (C 5);(H 5);(N 1)                  39.3               40.6 98234    NA         2311345   NA       NA        
5 CAD-392       Molecules pyrine                 (C 10);(H 9)                      393.               401.  NA       NA         5454678   NA       NA        
6 CAD-355       Groups    solution               (C 12);(H 12)                      32.5               40.7 NA       NA         NA        NA       NA        
7 CPD-39234     Compounds glycerophosphoglycerol (C 19);(H 29);(N 5);(O 10);(S 2)   92.4              101.  45465    NA         NA        33490    NA
```

Comment: All of those `mutate()` calls could be grouped into one, but separating them makes the code easier for me to read.

Answer (score 1):

Try narrowing your question to a minimal example of what you need. For example, the `SOURCE` column of your data frame has the string you'd like to match regular expressions:

```
SOURCE <- '(SPIDER "3315400" NIL | devarsh | 3468 NIL);(PUBCHEM "54758713" NIL | ong)'
```

You can extract groups of stuff using parentheses `()` where each parentheses is a new group and you can have a group inside another group:

```
pattern <- "((PUBCHEM) \"([0-9]*))"
regmatches(SOURCE, regexec(pattern, SOURCE))
```

Gives you a vector of 4 strings, each corresponding to a group. Vector elements 3 and 4 hold `PUBCHEM` AND `54758713`.